# Caption a tikzpicture on standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, captions, standalone

Title says it all:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    title=myTtitle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (10, 1) 
        (20, 2)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Error:

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

on `\begin{figure}`.

Shall you change `standalone` to `document` it will work, but it will make the plot so small in comparison with the `standalone` version... :/

Comment: Add the `varwidth` option to the documentclass, but why do you want to do this at all?

Comment: or `preview`, result differ from case of use `varwidth` (caption is centerred).

Comment: standalone is meant to provide the smallest document page possible and you are trying to put a float in it which obviously cannot *float*

Comment: I assume you want to use this to test the figure before copying it into the document WITH NO CHANGES.  The simplest fix is to place the figure inside a minipage with some predetermined width.   (Note, all the figure does is set \@captype to figure.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same result as with John Kormylo answer you obtain with option `preview` of `standalone` package (with out use of mini pages), so see extended version of my comment:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    name=border,
    title=myTtitle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (10, 1)
        (20, 2)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A caption.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I centered the axis box rather than the "axis plus labels" (assuming the left offset is larger than the right offset).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength{\offset}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5in}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    name=border,
    title=myTtitle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (10, 1) 
        (20, 2)
    };
  \end{axis}
  \pgfextractx{\offset}{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{west}}% center axis, not labels
  \path (border.east) +(-\offset,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please, can you explain, what connection has your answer to this question?

Comment: The minipage answers the question.  It just looked odd with the caption not aligned with the title.

Comment: Well, I must confess, that I don't understand your answer. By the way, in your MWE is missing `\documentclass`. And both first  comments above somehow solved the OP problem. Apparently OP is happy with your answer, so I have not rights to say anything more :-)

Comment: @Zarko - I added the missing lines.  Sorry about that.